# Kafka empty consumer groups are not being deleted automatically

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

We are using kafka 2.5.0 and due to application issue/bad architecture our cluster has more than 250,000 conusmer groups (most of them are empty).
Moreover when the cluster was created the config `offsets.retention.minutes` was set to a very big number.
More than a week ago we changed `offsets.retention.minutes` to 10080 (week) and made sure that `offsets.retention.check.interval.ms` is set to the default (10 minutes) and then restarted the cluster.
We monitored some old consumer groups (which are empty) and even after a week they are not being deleted.
Is their any other config that may interfere with `offsets.retention.minutes` or does kafka not able to handle the delete logic with so many groups?

Comment: Those groups won't be deleted until the segments of the offsets topic containing them are closed, as with any other topic

Comment: hi @OneCricketeer, can you please elaborate on that notion? in my lab I changed offset.retention.minutes to 5 and set offsets.retention.check.interval.ms to 60000 (minute) then I created a topic and using the console consumer utility i created a consumer group read a message and killed it. 5 minutes later the consumer group didn't exist as expected without doing anything else.

Comment: Singular groups are never really deleted, they just might be hidden in the API, but groups are truly deleted in batches. The `__consumer_offsets` topic is managed like any other, to the best of my knowledge. Obviously with more groups, that topic is larger, and the LogCleaner might be slower. So, to debug, you should inspect the actual files on the brokers and try using the log segment dump tool w/ grep

Comment: Thanks we will try that. Also do you know if there is any relevancy/connection between the log retention (log.retention.hours) and the offset retention?

Comment: Shouldn't be a connection. The former property is for non compact topics